# Columns will not sort Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In [this](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/zYBGowJ) codepen I have a Vue table where I am passing in the column name that is being clicked in order to sort by the column. I can console log the column name from the function to see if it is being launched the columns will not sort. What am I missing? Thank you.

```js
var table = new Vue({
  el: '#table',
  data: {
    ascending: false,
    sortColumn: '',
    rows: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Red"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Blue"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Green"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: "Brown"
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        name: "Grey"
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        name: "Pink"
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    "sortTable": function sortTable(col) {
      console.log(col)
      if (this.sortColumn === col) {
        this.ascending = !this.ascending;
      } else {
        this.ascending = true;
        this.sortColumn = col;
      }

      var ascending = this.ascending;

      this.rows.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (a[col] > b[col]) {
          return ascending ? 1 : -1
        } else if (a[col] < b[col]) {
          return ascending ? -1 : 1
        }
        return 0;
      })
    }
  },
  computed: {
    "columns": function columns() {
      if (this.rows.length == 0) {
        return [];
      }
      return Object.keys(this.rows[0])
    }
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  width: 750px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 3px solid #44475C;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 10px;
}

table th {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  background: #696969;
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px;
  min-width: 30px;
}

table th:hover {
  background: #A9A9A9;
}

table td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  border-right: 2px solid #696969;
}

table td:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

table tbody tr:nth-child(2n) td {
  background: #D3D3D3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th v-on:click="sortTable('ID')">ID</th>
      <th v-on:click="sortTable('Name')">Name</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="row in rows">
      <td>{{row.id}}</td>
      <td>{{row.name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javascript is case sensitive, try

```
<th v-on:click="sortTable('id')">ID</th>
<th v-on:click="sortTable('name')">Name</th>
```

note the `id` and `name` as the arguments to `sortTable` - which are the name of the keys in the table (rather than `ID` and `Name`)

```js
var table = new Vue({
  el: '#table',
  data: {
    ascending: false,
    sortColumn: '',
    rows: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Red"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Blue"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Green"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: "Brown"
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        name: "Grey"
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        name: "Pink"
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    "sortTable": function sortTable(col) {
      console.log(col)
      if (this.sortColumn === col) {
        this.ascending = !this.ascending;
      } else {
        this.ascending = true;
        this.sortColumn = col;
      }

      var ascending = this.ascending;

      this.rows.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (a[col] > b[col]) {
          return ascending ? 1 : -1
        } else if (a[col] < b[col]) {
          return ascending ? -1 : 1
        }
        return 0;
      })
    }
  },
  computed: {
    "columns": function columns() {
      if (this.rows.length == 0) {
        return [];
      }
      return Object.keys(this.rows[0])
    }
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  width: 750px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 3px solid #44475C;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 10px;
}

table th {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  background: #696969;
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px;
  min-width: 30px;
}

table th:hover {
  background: #A9A9A9;
}

table td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  border-right: 2px solid #696969;
}

table td:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

table tbody tr:nth-child(2n) td {
  background: #D3D3D3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th v-on:click="sortTable('id')">ID</th>
      <th v-on:click="sortTable('name')">Name</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="row in rows">
      <td>{{row.id}}</td>
      <td>{{row.name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```